# Can someone explain why the error and filtered signals are switching alternatively with Least mean square adaptive filtering

Tags: matlab, least-squares

I have been working out from a longtime on adaptive filtering with leastmean square method but was unable to get the right way for the LMS implementation.

I implemented the following considering each pulse signal has 500 samples.For the first pulse signal(of 500 samples)the reference signal is generated from the lowpass filter of the pulse signal and then using the generated error as reference noise signal for the next pulse signals

```
P=load('Pulse_signal.mat');
a2=P.a(334:4500,:);
for i=1:500:length(a2)-500   
    if(i<500)
        input=a2(i:i+499,:); 
        detected(i:i+499,:)=input; 
          d = fdesign.lowpass('Fp,Fst,Ap,Ast',1.5,8,0.5,20,500);
          Hd1 = design(d);
          filtered = filtfilt(Hd1.Numerator,1,input);              
          [w,y,e,W]=simple_LMS1(filtered,input,0.08,5);   
          e2(i:i+499,:)=e;      
          y2(i:i+499,:)= y;
      else        
          input=a2(i:i+499,:);  
          detected(i:i+499,:)=input; 
          [w,y,e,W]=simple_LMS1(e,input,0.08,8);         
          e2(i:i+499,:)=e;
          y2(i:i+499,:)= y;               
      end;
  end
  plot(detected);hold on;plot(e2,'-r');hold on;plot(y2,'-k');
simple_LMS1 fucntion

function [w,y,e,W] = simple_LMS1(x,d,mu_step,M)
N = length(x);
 y = zeros(N,1); 
 w = zeros(M,1); 
e = zeros(N,1); 
W = zeros(M,N); 
for n = 1:N
  if n <= M % assume zero-samples for delayed data that isn't available
      k = n:-1:1;
      x1 = [x(k); zeros(M-numel(k),1)];
  else
      x1 = x(n:-1:n-M+1); % M samples of x in reverse order
  end
  y(n) = w'*x1; 
  e(n) = d(n) - y(n); 
  w = w + mu_step*e(n)'*x1;
  W(:,n) = w; 
end
```

Problem: The output(more or less similar to input) is being alternatively shifted between the error signal and filtered signal as shown in the image below.[output](http://img706.imageshack.us/img706/6123/twik.jpg)

Is something wrong with my implementation itself?

Answer (score 0):

Several things does not seem right in the code. For the first 500 samples, you have a filtered signal and its input. You are trying to find the input from the filtered signal. That is, you are trying to invert the lowpass filter operation. Is that what you are trying to do?

In your LMS filter you are not saving filter states and filter weights between calls. You are essentially resetting your filter after every 500 samples and starting fresh. This is going to show discontinuities in the output after every 500 samples. This is what you are observing. I still do not know what logic you are trying to implement for samples above 500. You are trying to find a filter which creates input from the error obtained for first 500 samples?